# JQuery drop down menu on hover

Tags: jquery, menu, slidedown

I have a menu with multiple links which on hover a drop down menu slides down. Each link has its own drop down. My issue is that when you call a lot of events by moving your mouse in and out of the hover size it keeps sliding up and down even when you stop the hover.

```
setInterval(function(){

    if($("header nav ul li.product:hover").length != 0){
        $("header .dropdown-support").slideUp("slow", function(){
            alert();
            $("header .dropdown-product").slideDown(500);
        });
        $("header .dropdown-store").slideUp(500, function(){
            $("header .dropdown-product").slideDown(500);
        });
    }
    else{
        if($("header .menu-dropdown:hover").length == 0 && $("header nav ul:hover").length == 0){
            $("header .dropdown-product").slideUp();
        }
    }

    if($("header nav ul li.support:hover").length != 0){
        $("header .dropdown-product").slideUp(500, function(){
            $("header .dropdown-support").slideDown(500);
        });
        $("header .dropdown-store").slideUp(500, function(){
            $("header .dropdown-support").slideDown(500);
        });
    }
    else{
        if($("header .menu-dropdown:hover").length == 0 && $("header nav ul:hover").length == 0){
            $("header .dropdown-support").slideUp();
        }
    }

    if($("header nav ul li.store:hover").length != 0){
        $("header .dropdown-product").slideUp(500, function(){
            $("header .dropdown-store").slideDown();
        });
        $("header .dropdown-support").slideUp(500, function(){
            $("header .dropdown-store").slideDown();
        });
    }
    else{
        if($("header .menu-dropdown:hover").length == 0 && $("header nav ul:hover").length == 0){
            $("header .dropdown-store").slideUp();
        }
    }
}, 500);
```

Similar to this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/4jxph/2/

Anyone has any idea how can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `jquery.stop()` function.

```js
$("header .dropdown-support").stop().slideUp(500, function(){
    $("header .dropdown-store").stop().slideDown();
});
```